# How to use external JavaScript script in Angular that is not available as a node module

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to integrate a payment system into my Ionic/Angular android app and I cannot figure out how to use the JavaScript script they sent me that is supposed to be used to create the payment frame.

I have linked the js file in the angular.json file. But what I cannot figure out is how to actually use the script in my component.

I have already tried adding a typings.d.ts to the src folder. In which I added:

```
    declare let ozow: any;
```

ozow being the function that is being exported, I then proceeded to add:

```
    import * as variable from ozow
```

but this also did not work.

I also tried adding the following to my component:

```
    declare let ozow:any
```

but that also did not work.

Here is the javascript file I am trying to make use of in my angular project:

```
var ozow = (function(e, t, a) {
    var n = e.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent",
        r = "/payment/iframeredirect?redirecturl=",
        o = "Payment could not be completed, please contact the site administrator";

    function l(e) {
        return (
            e.CancelUrl &&
            e.CancelUrl.length > 0 &&
            (e.CancelUrl = r + encodeURI(e.CancelUrl)),
            e.ErrorUrl &&
            e.ErrorUrl.length > 0 &&
            (e.ErrorUrl = r + encodeURI(e.ErrorUrl)),
            e.SuccessUrl &&
            e.SuccessUrl.length > 0 &&
            (e.SuccessUrl = r + encodeURI(e.SuccessUrl)),
            e
        );
    }
    return (
        (0, e[n])(
            "attachEvent" == n ? "onmessage" : "message",
            function(a) {
                if (
                    a.data &&
                    a.data.event &&
                    ("ozowMessage" == a.data.event || "ozowResize" == a.data.event)
                )
                    if ("ozowMessage" == a.data.event) {
                        var n = Object.keys(a.data.postData)
                            .map(function(e) {
                                return (
                                    encodeURIComponent(e) +
                                    "=" +
                                    encodeURIComponent(a.data.postData[e])
                                );
                            })
                            .join("&");
                        e.location =
                            a.data.url +
                            (-1 == a.data.url.indexOf("?") ? "?" : "&") +
                            (n || {});
                    } else
                        "ozowResize" == a.data.event &&
                        (t.getElementById("paymentFrame").style.height =
                            a.data.height + "px");
            },
            !1
        ),
        function() {
            var e = this;
            (e.createPaymentFrame = function(e, a, n) {
                if (!e || "" == e || 0 == e.length)
                    return (
                        console.log(
                            "The createPaymentFrame method parameter elementSelector cannot be empty or null."
                        ),
                        void alert(o)
                    );
                if (!a || "" == a || 0 == a.length)
                    return (
                        console.log(
                            "The createPaymentFrame method parameter paymentUrl cannot be empty or null."
                        ),
                        void alert(o)
                    );
                if (t.getElementById("paymentFrame")) {
                    var r = t.getElementById("paymentFrame");
                    r.parentNode.removeChild(r);
                }
                if ("object" == typeof n) {
                    l(n),
                        (a =
                            a +
                            "?viewName=JsInjection&" +
                            Object.keys(n)
                            .map(function(e) {
                                return encodeURIComponent(e) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(n[e]);
                            })
                            .join("&"));
                    var i = t.createElement("iframe");
                    i.setAttribute("id", "paymentFrame"),
                        i.setAttribute("src", a),
                        i.setAttribute("frameborder", "0"),
                        i.setAttribute("scrolling", "no"),
                        i.setAttribute("height", "100%"),
                        i.setAttribute("width", "100%"),
                        (i.style.overflow = "hidden"),
                        (i.style.height = "100%"),
                        (i.style.width = "100%"),
                        t.getElementById(e).appendChild(i);
                } else
                    console.log(
                        "The createPaymentFrame method expects a JSON object for the postData parameter."
                    ),
                    alert(o);
            }),
            (e.createPaymentModal = function(e, a) {
                if (!e || "" == e || 0 == e.length)
                    return (
                        console.log(
                            "The createPaymentModal method parameter paymentUrl cannot be empty or null."
                        ),
                        void alert(o)
                    );
                if (t.getElementById("paymentFrame")) {
                    var n = t.getElementById("paymentFrame");
                    n.parentNode.removeChild(n);
                }
                if ("object" == typeof a) {
                    l(a),
                        (e =
                            e +
                            "?viewName=JsPopup&" +
                            Object.keys(a)
                            .map(function(e) {
                                return (
                                    encodeURIComponent(e) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(a[e])
                                );
                            })
                            .join("&"));
                    var r = t.createElement("iframe");
                    r.setAttribute("id", "paymentFrame"),
                        r.setAttribute("src", e),
                        r.setAttribute("frameborder", "0"),
                        r.setAttribute("scrolling", "no"),
                        (r.style.position = "fixed"),
                        (r.style.left = "0"),
                        (r.style.right = "0"),
                        (r.style.bottom = "0"),
                        (r.style.top = "0"),
                        (r.style.width = "100%"),
                        (r.style.height = "175%"),
                        t.body.appendChild(r);
                } else
                    console.log(
                        "The createPaymentModal method expects a JSON object for the postData parameter."
                    ),
                    alert(o);
            }),
            (e.cancelFramePayment = function() {
                t.getElementById("paymentFrame").contentWindow.postMessage({
                        event: "ozowCancelPayment"
                    },
                    "*"
                );
            });
        }
    );
})(window, document);
```

Please note this is a file that was sent to me by them directly. The function that the instructions said to call is ozow.createPaymentFrame but I cannot get to the point where I can successfully call this function.

Below are the instructions found in the README.md

```
1. Add a container element onto your page and assign it a unique id value, i.e. a div etc., this element will be the container for the Ozow payment iframe.
   Eg. <div id="paymentContainer"></div>
2. Add a trigger element onto your page and assign it a unique id value, i.e. a radio button, button etc., the element will be a option that displays pay using Ozow and will also trigger the Ozow payment frame.
   Eg. <input type="radio" id="payUsingOzow" value="Ozow"> Ozow
3. Add cancel element onto your your page and assign it a unique id value, i.e. button etc., this element will be used to cancel payment using the Ozow payment frame.
   Eg. <input type="button" id="cancelOzowPayment" name="cancelOzowPayment" value="Cancel Payment">
4. Inside an existing or new JavaScript script block on your page instantiate the ozow jsintegration module and assign it to a variable.
   Eg. <script>
            var ozow = new Ozow();
       </script>
5. Create an event listener for the trigger element and add code inside the event listener to load the Ozow payment frame, i.e. onclick, onchange etc.
   Eg. JavaScript: trigger_element_id.onclick = function(){
         var containerElement = document.getElementById('container_element_id'); //The container element where Ozow payment frame will be loaded
         var paymentUrl = 'https://pay.ozow.com/'; //The URL to process Ozow payments
         var postData = {}; //The form data, which should contain all the required Ozow post variables, serialized as JSON object
         ozow.createPaymentFrame(containerElement, paymentUrl, postData); //The method that initiate loading the Ozow payment frame
       }; or 
       jQuery: $('trigger_element_id').click(function(){
         var containerElement = $('container_element_id'); //The container element where Ozow payment frame will be loaded
         var paymentUrl = 'https://pay.ozow.com/'; //The URL to process Ozow payments
         var postData = {}; //The form data, which should contain all the required Ozow post variables, serialized as JSON object
         ozow.createPaymentFrame(containerElement, paymentUrl, postData); //The method that initiate loading the Ozow payment frame
       });
6. Create event listener for the cancel element and add code inside the event listener to cancel the Ozow payment, i.e. onclick, onchange etc.
   Eg. JavaScript: cancel_element_id.onclick = function(){
         ozow.cancelFramePayment(); //The method that will call and instruct Ozow to cancel the payment
       }; or 
       jQuery: $('cancel_element_id').click(function(){
         ozow.cancelFramePayment(); //The method that will call and instruct Ozow to cancel the payment
       });
```

Thank you in adavnce for your support.

Additonal Notes:

1. It is a javascript runtime error and not a typescript compilation error
2. The error I am getting is that ozow.createPaymentFrame is not a function
3. I added the js script to the angular.json file. Below is the entire script section from the angular.json file

```
"scripts": [
 "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
 "./src/assets/js/ipay-noredirect-1.0.min.js"
],
```

Please note I also tried :

```
 "src/assets/js/ipay-noredirect-1.0.min.js"
```

Comment: What's the problem with `declare let ozow:any`? `ozow` should be globally available in JavaScript. The declaration is only for TypeScript. I guess, the unique IDs are recommendations and not really necessary. The only necessary ID seems to be `paymentFrame`, but this element is generated by the script. What exactly are you struggling with? Do you know how to add click listeners in Angular? Do you know how to access elements in templates?

Comment: I am struggling with using ozow. I get an error in the console saying it is not a function. I assumed its because angular doesnt know what I am trying to call.

And yes, I know how to add click listeners and I know how to access elements in templates. The only problem I am facing is actually using the ozow function.

Comment: What is not a function? How did you add the script to `angular.json`?

Comment: My mistake. ozow.createPaymentFrame is not a function, is the error I am getting.

Comment: Is this a TypeScript transpiler error or a JavaScript runtime error? Do you see the script in the dev tools? You should see it in the Inspector as a HTML element, in the Debugger and in the Network Monitor.

Comment: I believe it is a runtime error. Compilation succeeds as far as I can see.

Comment: How did you add the script to `angular.json`? Do you see the script in the dev tools? You should see it in Inspector/Elements as an HTML element and in the Debugger as dependency. I don't remember whether this scripts are also bundled or visible in the Network tab as requests.

Comment: I added it to the scripts section in the angular.json file. I see it in the network monitor but not as an html element. That might just be a problem on my side but I do not see it as an element.

Comment: You can see it in the Network tab but not in the DOM? That doesn't make sense. First, it's added to the DOM and from there the network request is initiated.

Comment: I noticed that I manually added the script to the index.html. I removed it and now I am no longer seeing the js file in the network tab. But when it was there there were no errors.

Comment: It seems like you didn't add it correctly to `angular.json`.

Comment: I tried `"./src/assets/js/ipay-noredirect-1.0.min.js"` and `"src/assets/js/ipay-noredirect-1.0.min.js"`

But none of those result in me seeing the script in the network monitor

this is the entire scripts section: 

`            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./src/assets/js/ipay-noredirect-1.0.min.js"
            ],
`

Comment: Did you do `var ozow = new Ozow();`? I would say the instructions are wrong. There is no `Ozow` in the script. I would ask the support.

Comment: I did not do that. As I also saw there is no Ozow. I shall contact support.